# Problems with Opera and getLoginUrl()

Tags: authentication, facebook-php-sdk

I've been googling a lot, but seems that no-one has had this strange problem.
I'm using Php sdk to perform facebook authentication, we initialize our Facebook-app:

```
<?php     $fb = new Facebook(array('appId' => 'our-app-id', 'secret' => 'our-secret'));     ?>
```

and print the link with the href value obtained by:

```
<?php $lu = $fb->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri' => 'www.ourdomain/fblogin')); ?>
```

with 'redirect-uri' pointing to a page that checks request parameters, but does not perform any redirect, according to documentation.
Authentication works well in every browser, except Opera (i have latest version 11.6).

The user can allow the application, but when he clicks 'Login' redirecting doesn't work. It performs authentication, because when i go to Facebook homepage I am logged in, but is not able to perform redirect to my url
I've tried to disable the opera browser.js to prevent it modifying Facebook scripts, but still doesn't work.
Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Same Problem. Seems if the redirect succeeded, but the result page was cached (althoug my url changed!)

Comment: here's the answer:
http://my.opera.com/chooseopera/blog/show.dml/9014631